# Yet another question on disjoint and independent events

Tags: probability

Continued from last time, I am still struggling to find examples for (non-)disjoint and (in)dependent events. Based on my understanding so far.

1. Two disjoint but independent events

Naive example: Roll a die and define events $E$ "roll 6" and $F$ "roll 3."

They are disjoint because you can't roll both 3 and 6 at the same time.

Disjoint events are mutually exclusive so they can't be independent. Event independence requires the relation $P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$ to be satisfied. $P(E\cap F)=0$ here.

There are exceptions. For example, consider the game of darts. Define events $E$ "dart land on target" and $F$ "dart land on the edge of the board." $P(E\cap F)=0$ since a dart land at both places same time but $P(E)=0$ and $P(F)=0$ since there are infinitely many points but it is still possible to land on one of them. Events $E$ and $F$ are disjoint but independent events.

2. Two disjoint but dependent events

I think it is impossible.

**Question: Is it true that there is no such thing as disjoint but dependent events? If not, what are counterexamples? Maybe see number 4.**

3. Non-disjoint but independent events

Consider an experiment where we roll two fair dice. Define events $E$ "the sum of the face values is $7$" and $F$ the face value of the first die is $1$.

$E$ and $F$ are not disjoint because there is a possible outcome where the sum of the face value is $7$ and the face value of the first die is $1$: $\{1, 6\}$.

$E$ and $F$ are independent because $P(E\cap F)=\frac{1}{36}$ and $P(E)P(F)=\frac{1}{36}$

4. Non-disjoint but dependent events

In an experiment where you draw two balls from a bag containing $5$ red balls and $3$ green balls without replacement, define events $E$ "draw a red ball on the first draw" and $F$ "two balls are red."

$E$ and $F$ are not disjoint because there is an outcome where $E$ and $F$ happens at the same time: $\{R, R\}$.

$E$ and $F$ are dependent (ie. not independent) because $P(E\cap F)=\frac58 \frac47=\frac{5}{14}$ and $P(E)P(F)=\frac58 \frac{5}{14}=\frac{25}{112}$.

**Question: If I redefine event $F$ to be "the first ball drawn is green," will that make events disjoint? If so, does it make an example of disjoint but dependent event?**

Comment: Re $2$. Didn't you just show that disjoint events are usually dependent? Or do you have a different definition of "dependent" than "not independent"?

Comment: @BrianTung where? I am not sure why disjoint events should be dependent

Comment: "Dependent" just means "not independent", right? If events are disjoint, so mutually exclusive, so not independent (unless they have probability zero), then they are dependent, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see but I need an explicit example that shows disjoint events are dependent so I can understand it. Do you have any?

Comment: Look at your very first example, with the two dice rolls.

Comment: Think of "E and F are independent" as "Finding out about E has no effect on the probability of F".

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's for a single dice roll. Also, does it indicate $P(E|F)=0$?

Comment: I don't understand your objection to "a single dice roll". Rolling a six is an event. Rolling a three is an event. Those two events are disjoint, and they are dependent (in that they are not independent). That's what you wanted. As for $P(E|F)$, that notation is defined by a formula. If you know that formula, then you will have no difficulty deducing whether $P(E|F)=0$. So: do you know the formula that defines $P(E|F)$?

Comment: Jimmy Yang, you said, "Disjoint events are mutually exclusive so they can't be independent." (Proviso: Both events must have non-zero probability to conclude this.) Therefore they must be dependent, mustn't they?

Comment: Yes, I realized that.